# What C++ compiler does Android studio use

Tags: android, c++, android-studio

Is it GCC or LLVM, I assume it's not LLVM by default as the option is unchecked in SDK manager yet I can build an Android project with C++ support.

Comment: Why do you wonder? What is the problem you are having? Or is it just simple curiosity?

Comment: Please read: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html

Explains everything properly. :D

Comment: I wonder as I see LLVM is unchecked in the Android SDK so main other C++ compiler is GCC, and I wonder which of these two is better compiler to use.